# Define a region with XY Coordinates

Tags: sikuli

I am working with Sikuli 1.1.0 and I am a bit stuck on the following issue:

I have a XY Location of my image, named `valueLocXY`. 
Now I would like to define a region left from it.

When looking for images and defining a region I use:

```
image1Loc = find("image1.png")
regionImage = image1Loc.left(100)
```

But when I use this for XY coordinates it won't work. 
Does anyone know how to do this with XY coordinates?

Edit:

```
valueLoc = find(value)
valueLocXY = Location(valueLoc.getX(), valueLoc.getY())
```

`value` is the input from the definition (word) we are looking for.

Comment: Can you please a full example? Are those coordinates are just two integers or is that a Sikuli Location class?

Comment: Adding an example where XY comes from.